# Mixing valve for bath

Tags: bathtub

I saw my mixing valve under the bath that is so dirty. Is it normal? Thanks[image]

Comment: no ............

Comment: The only thing unusual about this is the galvanized steel bodied mixing valve. What's the manufacturer and model?

Answer (score 1):

Is that normal? Yes.

Common? Yes. You'll find plumbing in a similar state in probably hundreds of thousands of homes in the united states.

It is a problem waiting to happen? Yes.

Is it dirty? No.

That bad boy right there is good and corroded. A good candidate for proactive replacement. In the future, whether you wait for a leak (which could be a blow out or could be a pinhead) or you go ahead with replacing now, find a valve with solid brass connections to play nice with the copper. whenever you go to replace, give that adjacent copper a good look over to see if any of it looks like you need to cut it back and replace with new.

Comment: @Kammi please take the [tour] so you'll know the proper way of saying "thanks".